# How to add a statement at the end of a line containing a macro in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, macros

To reduce the number of lines to be written, i am using macros in the following way:

```
#define FUNC(a, b)  func(a, b, threadId, sizeof(a)); \
                      do something 1;                 \
                      do something 2;
```

This works well, as i just need to use the macro (with 2 parameters) that encodes the function call (with 4 parameters) and 2 or more other statements.

Problem arises when this function call is a parameter to another function.
For example, suppose i need the following code:

```
func1(par1, func(a, b, c, d));
do something 1;
do something 2;
```

Is there a way to achieve this using macros, or any other alternatives?
i.e. I am expecting something like:

```
func1(par1, FUNC(a, b)); //This statement(using macros) should transform into the above code after the preprocessing step.
```

Comment: Even if it were, it would be a horrible idea IMO as it would make the macro have strange effects that are not immediately visible to a programmer reading the code.

Comment: This is not a good fit for a macro. I would replace the macro with a regular function.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are trying to do such a thing ? This smells like a typical [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: Are you using C or C++? In one of the languages you can overload functions and write `void func(type a, int b) { func(a, b, threadId, sizeof(a)); }` without macros.

Comment: @MichaelWalz The only reason i am using macros is to reduce the number of lines, and to produce clean code. The function func is being called many times, and each call of func is followed by additional statements.

Comment: @ceedee, well in that case follow what is suggested in the second comment. Your idea of using macros here is really terrible and I don't see any advantage. If the function is called many times and if it's _always_ followed by those additionnal statements, then why don't you just put the statmentents _into_ the function ?

Comment: @BoPersson I am using C++. Thanks for your suggestion. I understand your suggestion would help me reduce the number of parameters, but i would also like to avoid writing the 2 subsequent statements after each function call.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Because the function func is part of an API being implemented by me, and the additional statements are supposed to be part of the application that does some work based on a value modified by the function.

Comment: @ceedee see my answer below.

Comment: Why don't you make FUNC a (template) function? And, for the second use case (passing func() to another function), make a second (template) function for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are *actually* trying to achieve, but replacing this:

```
#define FUNC(a, b)  func(a, b, threadId, sizeof(a)); \
                  do something 1;                 \
                  do something 2;
```

by this (assuming the type of the `a` and `b` parameters is `int`):

```
int FUNC(int a, int b)
{
  int returnvalue = func(a,b,threadId, sizeof(a));
  do something 1;
  do something 2;
  return returnvalue;
}
```

should do the job.

Comment: Your solution would let me express the first code block in my question without using Macros. I was able to achieve the same using macros, but i now understand the benefit of doing this without macros. However, the problem is when the function func is used as a parameter in another function, just like in the 2nd code block in my question. Is there a way to express it with or without macros?

Comment: Your solution with macros is broken, and as far as I know there is no solution with macros. Is my answer working or not for your case ? If not please tell me why.

Comment: It does work. I was not sure if this would work because the function func is part of a library implemented by me, and other functionalities in my code. However it worked, i guess i got blinded by macros. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to isolate the code with brackets { }. But your idea is not one I would recommend, as the code becomes very hard to understand and debug.

```
#define FUNC(a, b) { func(a, b, threadId, sizeof(a)); \
                      do something 1;                 \
                      do something 2; }
```

But if you try to send this as a parameter to another function it still won't work because you are not returning anything to be uses as a parameter ( no adress, no value)

Comment: This is not an answer but rather a comment. You just give the advice to use `{}`, but the actual question remains unanswered.